# div overflow on one side only?

Tags: css, html, overflow

Is it possible to make a div over flow on one side only?

So an image can flow out of the right side of a parent div, but not below, above, or right.

Or would I have to float divs above the areas I do not want content to show from?

Comment: The overflow-x property does not work properly in IE8 and earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you align the image to the left, it should never spill out on that side. Then all you have to do is

```
div{
 overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

This will prevent overflow in the top and bottom directions.

Comment: Sometimes it's the box-shadow you need overhanging the edge. So, I want my image to shift offscreen on the right, but not get it's box-shadow cut off by it's container div on the left.

Answer (score 1):

As per i understand may be you  have to use `overflow-x` & `overflow-y` property  that's you want:

```
div{
 overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 has `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`, so that you can specify overflow in horizontal and vertical direction seperately, but not right only.